# Wordpress Jetpack Infinite Scroll returning {"type":"empty"}

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I've installed Wordpress Jetpack and configured everything in my `functions.php`, but for some reason it's not working. I've followed [these instructions](http://ottopress.com/2012/jetpack-and-the-infinite-scroll/), and those on the Jetpack website, but nothing seems to load in... Developer tools show the AJAX response to be `{“type”:“empty”}`.

I wish to load items from a custom taxonomy. On the `archive.php` page I have a simple bit of PHP that loads things in:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

`content.php` contains the template for each of the posts, and as a static page, it works fine. I've installed Jetpack and placed the following in my `functions.php`:

```
function bones_infinite_loop_init(){
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'type'           => 'scroll',
        'container'      => 'masonry',
        'render'         => 'bones_infinite_scroll_render',
        'footer'         => false
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'bones_infinite_loop_init' );

function bones_infinite_scroll_render() { 
$args = array( 'post_type'=> 'wigwam','post_parent' => 0,'posts_per_page' => 25);
    query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile; 
endif;
}
```

But nothing is coming in. How can I debug this?